# Add source to both local TFS and TFSPreview

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to add your projects/source to two different TFS servers?
If possible it would be very handy to synchronize my local TFS server with TFSPreview.

Comment: I would be surprised if this was possible, I've not heard of any SCM tool that can do this.

Comment: Why do you want it in two different repositories?

Comment: Hi Ewald!  I have heard this frequently actually.  It's similar to the reasons there is a Pioneer server and a centralized DEVDIV server.  Specifically while it is in "Preview" people want to be able sync it with on-premises but I see valid scenarios even after "Preview" where this would be desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely not supported. TFS stores cache of your local workspaces and will never allow you to map the same folder to two different servers. This is how you can work with tf.exe without specifying server switch every time.
Very simple solution for you is to mirror one workspace with robocopy in another directory. Before you start doing something on your own please look at http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/. TFS product team is afaik using it exactly for purpose of synchronizing between 2 servers.